# Как создать массивы из 96 подмассивов с присвоением уникального адреса?

Tags: python-3.x, массивы, numpy

Есть массив, состоящий из 96 строк и 67 столбцов. Я его разбил по столбцам, при помощи `np.hsplit`

Как теперь преобразовать все эти подмассивы в самостоятельные массивы, чтобы каждому присвоился уникальный адрес автоматом?

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sample = pickle.loads(open('pt_sample.pkl', 'rb').read())
sample = sample.T
sample=sample.resample('H', kind='period').mean()

df0 = sample.filter(regex='CT')
m = np.hsplit(df0, 67)
```

Comment: А какой смысл сего действа?

Comment: чтобы между ними потом кросс корреляцию провести

Comment: @Xsandr21, и у Pandas.DataFrame и у Numpy.NDArray есть методы для расчета кросскореляции столбцов. Поэтому все еще непонятно зачем разбивать матрицу на отдельные столбцы

Comment: так вот, сидел изучал этот вопрос https://pyprog.pro/statistics_functions/correlate.html

Но так понял, что для корректной кросскорреляции нужно, чтобы массивы были одинаковой размерности.
А столбцы эти с параметрами от разных источников, дающих сигнал через определенный временной интервал.  Вот и подумал, что надо разбить их по столбцам, а потом уже друг с другом сравнивать.
Ладу еще дать не могу, к сожалению, поэтому спросил совета.
Но, все равно спасибо, буду разбираться дальше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
np.random.seed(31415)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(20, size=(10, 5)), columns=list("abcde"))
```

фрейм:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
    a   b   c   d   e
0   7   3  13   5   8
1  18   6   6   3  14
2   6  16  16   8  19
3   6  17  12   1  10
4   4   6  14   2   7
5  18   2  19  10  19
6   9   8   3  11  14
7  19   2  16   0   4
8  18   6  14  14  16
9   2   6   6  12  15
```

корреляция:

```
In [32]: df.corr()
Out[32]:
          a         b         c         d         e
a  1.000000 -0.477557  0.274701 -0.000653  0.076438
b -0.477557  1.000000 -0.096274 -0.088437  0.249301
c  0.274701 -0.096274  1.000000 -0.184259 -0.035054
d -0.000653 -0.088437 -0.184259  1.000000  0.750541
e  0.076438  0.249301 -0.035054  0.750541  1.000000
```

По главной диагонали всегда будут единицы, т.к. сравниваем столбец с самим собой.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.
Разобрался вчера еще. Действительно, не было смысла разбивать по столбцам, это я вчера не в ту степь пошел ) Вы были абсолютно правы.
С корреляцией также разобрался, просто отфильтровав нужные столбцы и проведя корреляцию между ними

Вот например:
dfCT = sample.filter(regex='CT')
CT = np.hsplit(dfCT, 67)
CT = dfCT.fillna(0)
correlation_dataCT = CT.corr()

Могу ли я попросить еще подсказку?
Как удалить из массива все элементы по условию, например все значения больше 0,9?

Comment: @Xsandr21, конечно можете - StackOverflow для этого и существует. :) Но я вам советую открыть новый вопрос, привести в нем небольшой воспроизводимый пример входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить